# Speech to text function slower in Windows and the same function is slower in ubuntu

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have this function for speech to text in one of my gen ai projects which works fine in windows(My PC)but takes too long to work on ubuntu(jetson orin).

```
   `def live_speech_to_text(self):
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Listening...")
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)

        try:
            print("Recognizing...")
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
            return text
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Could not request results from Google Web Speech API; {0}".format(e))`
```

It gets stuck after printing Recognizing... for about 2-3 mins which doesn't happen in my Windows low spec PC or any other Windows devices .
What could be the possible reasons and solutions.

I tried using other models like pocketsphinx and vosx but they weren't accurate at all but were fast enough to give results , looking for a faster alternative with good accuracy ,atleast close to google in English language only , not looking for expertise in any other languages.

Comment: Are both of these systems running on the same hardware? There are endless possibilities why code runs differently on different systems. The person with access to those systems (you) is best equipped to investigate the issue.